# Shell script to start the nginx when it quit unexpectly

Tags: bash, shell, nginx, monitor

Centos 6.0), and i find that my nginx will quit unexpectedly. So i want to write a shell script to start the nginx when it quit . Below is the script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 nginxBin=/usr/bin/nginx
 confFile=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 LOGS=/var/log/nginx/nginx.log
 restart_nginx() {
     echo " `date`---restart the nginx " >> $LOGS
     $nginxBin -c $confFile
  }

 while true
 do
     NGINX_NUM=`ps aux | grep "nginx" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
     if [ $NGINX_NUM -lt 2 ]; then
         restart_nginx
         continue
     fi                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     sleep 5
 done
```

And i put this in /etc/rc.local , but it when i kill the nginx for a test , it seems didn't work. For i'm not familiar with shell script .
Can anyone help me ? Thank you~~

zjhui

Comment: Your `if` statement goes the long way around: `if ps aux|grep "ngin[x]"; then...` should be OK, but I'm not sure that would make much difference.  Try running the script with `bash -x script-name` to get a trace.

Comment: Why does nginx die in the first place, anyway?

Comment: I don't know..My memory and cpu haven't over used anyway. And i don't know how to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

If your script's name includes the string `nginx`, it will commit suicide after 5 seconds.

If you have `pidof`, try with `pidof nginx` instead if the awkward double `grep`. Otherwise, try to tighten up your regex.

For the record, the customary way to avoid having `grep` return itself in a `ps` listing is to use a regex which doesn't match itself. For example, `ps aux | grep -c '[n]ginx'`. The `-c` gets rid of the `wc -l`. Maybe add a word boundary and/or anchors to avoid killing your own script (assuming it's called something like `respawn-nginxen`).

Comment: Thank you, your advise worked for me.  But i wonder , When i : echo "/bin/bash /path/to/nginx.sh" >> /etc/rc.local . Then i kill the nginx  process , the nginx didn't start automatically

Comment: And you fixed the script, and rebooted? Does the script work if you run it manually? I'm guessing it doesn't, and there's still something to fix.

Comment: hmm..i haven't reboot. But when i kill the nginx and start the script manually , the nginx can start but with a cursor , i should use Ctr-C to force quit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an init script fitting to your CentOS distribution?

An example can be read here: http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/2/2/centos-adding-an-nginx-init-script